# logger doesn't output info level even though it is enabled

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm creating a logger object. Set logging level to `logging.INFO`. After this I do  the following:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO)
True
```

Ok, now try this:

```
logger.info('123')
```

The last line prints nothing. However:

```
>>> logger.critical(123)
123
```

I know it has to be something very simple that I'm missing. What would that be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a handler, because by default there is none and it'll log only levels above a predefined last resort level.

Add this code after the line with `getLogger`:

```
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Also, look at the examples in the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).